# Split a String serval times using two caracters java

Tags: java, string, split, hashmap

I'm working on a function that takes a code (String characters) and put them in a hashmap, so talking about the code, it's always ULI_ULI_ULI...
U means User, L means nothing and N is an ID.
The caracter _ is to sépare between sets number, I mean if I have 3 records I'm getting ULI_ULI_ULI, if 2 ULI_ULI and if it's one one I will get ULI.
The goal is to get the U and I and insert them into a hashmap,
The steps:
1/ Split using _ in a table:

```
String s = code;
String[] a = s.split("_");
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
            }
```

The result:

```
2L1
3L1
4L2
```

2/ Split again using the L:
The result that I'm getting is

```
2
1
3
1
4
2
```

That's not what I really want. I want to get the character in index(0) and the index(2) of every first results and put them into a hashmap .

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: a hashmap<U,I> that I can use after

Comment: Do you mean add a mapping from `U` to `I` into the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there as you can it it all from the already defined loop

```
String s = code;
String[] a = s.split("_");
HashMap <String, String> result = new HashMap <String, String>();
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    String [] inner = a[i].split ("L");
    if (inner.length > 1) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s%n", inner [0], inner[1]);
        result.put (inner [0], inner[1]);
    }
}
```